Formula which is similar to Plancherel, for functions in Bochner spaces.
I am working on analysis in Bochner spaces. This field may be a bit niche, but I expect someone can answer or comment.
Let $X$ be a Banach space on $\mathbb C$. And let $1<p<\infty$, and assume $q$ is conjugate of $p.$
For $f\in L^p(\mathbb R, X)$ and $g\in L^q(\mathbb R, X^\ast)$, define the duality paring notation $(\cdot, \cdot)$ as
$$( f,g):=\int_{\mathbb R}\langle f(x), g(x)\rangle dx.$$
(This is well-defined by Holder's inequality.)
Now, I am wondering why this statement hold :
For $f\in L^1(\mathbb R, X)\cap L^2(\mathbb R, X)$ and $g\in L^1(\mathbb R, X^\ast)\cap L^2(\mathbb R, X^\ast)$, if $\check f\in L^2(\mathbb R, X)$ and $\check g \in L^2(\mathbb R, X^\ast)$, then $$(\check f, \check g)=(f,g),$$ where $\check f$ represents the fourier inverse transform of $f.$ (Note that LHS and RHS can be defined since the conjugate of $2$ is $2$.)
If $\check f$ or $\check g$ is in $L^1$, this formula can be derived by direct calculation with Fubini, but $\check f$ and $\check g$ are not necessarily in $L^1.$
This formula looks Plancherel's theorem for $\mathbb C$- valued function, but now, $f$ is $X$- valued and $g$ is $X^\ast$- valued function, and $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is not inner product, thus this is essentially different from Plancherel.
I have spent a lot of time investigating the reason for this formula, but cannot find so far. Does anyone have any idea or reference ?

Is there an equivalent of the Schwartz space but for Banach-valued functions, for which we'd have that the Fourier transform leaves said space invariant in the same way as the usual Schwartz space? Because if so you could just try to extend your result by density and bilinearity + continuity, right? I'm not confident as I haven't gone that far yet with Banach-valued functions though.

For Banach-valued functions, Schwartz space and its Fourier transform are defined in the same way as $\mathbb C$-valued functions. And even in Banach-valued theory, Schwartz space is dense in $L^p$ for $1\leqq p<\infty$ thus Schwartz space is dense in $L^2.$ Can I extend the result $(\check f, \check g)=(f,g)$ by density, bilinearity, and continuity ? @BrunoB

That would be reasonable then, yes. You could write your own answer if you'd like.

Really ? For $f,g$, there is sequenses of Schwartz functions ${f_n}$ and ${g_n}$ s.t. $|f-f_n|_2, |g-g_n|_2\to 0$. We have $(\check{f_n}, \check{g_n})=(f_n, g_n)$. Then we can see $(f_n, g_n)\to(f,g)$ by bilinearity and Holder. However,  how do we see $(\check{f_n}, \check{g_n})\to (\check f, \check g)$ ? @BrunoB

The Fourier transform and inverse Fourier transform remain unitary in that context, do they not? So that $|f_n - f|_2 = |\check{f_n} - \check{f}|_2$?

In Bochner spaces, the unitarity doesn't hold generally.

Ah, oh well, that was wishful thinking on my end. Sorry for not being able to help more, and have a nice day/night!
